# Is accessing to std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> while std::uint16_t is active inside a union well defined behavior?

Tags: c++

If I have an union

```cpp
union Bytes {
  std::uint16_t bytes;
  std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> split_bytes;
};
```

and I use it like this

```cpp
int main(){
  auto bytes = Bytes{0xFF'EE};
  // do something with bytes.split_bytes[0] and bytes.split_bytes[1]
}
```

Assuming the target machine is little endian, is my usage well-defined behavior?

Comment: Union type punning is always UB. Use `std::bit_cast`.

Comment: If you want to do conversion from some binary data to `uint16_t` just do respective bit shifts. Compiler will optimize this.

Comment: I'm using GCC with UBsan to compile this and GCC doesn't think this is UB. Is this a GCC extension?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Technically not always UB. There's one exceptionally well defined case of common initial sequence of standard layout structs.

Comment: @UyHà Probably.  GCC supports C, and in C this type of punning (yes, pun intended) is allowed

Comment: @UyHà I don't think there is a ubsan check for active union members in GCC. I don't think that would be easy to implement non-intrusively. UBsan only detects a small subset of common undefined behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is accessing to std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> while std::uint16_t is active inside a union well defined behavior?

Reading an inactive union member is undefined behaviour. Assigning an inactive trivial union member activates it.

Since the target of your attempted type punning is `std::uint8_t` which is `unsigned char`, you can use `reinterpret_cast` to read a `std::uint16_t`. However, as you seem to be aware, the order of the bytes varies between systems, and making assumptions about the order will result in a poorly portable program.

Comment: I'm asking this mostly for the convience when writing code, for which it seems like it's not worth it. As for being portable, I can do `if constexpr` on the endianess, the assumption is there just for brevity.

Comment: @UyHà `I can do if constexpr on the endianess` But you don't need to. If you use bit shifts, you can write one code that works on all systems.

Comment: Yeah, I'm awared of that, this is more like an attempt to see if I am able skip the shiftings, but for standard C++, and considering the effort of dealing with the endianess, it's a profounding no then.

Comment: Is there a way to use `reinterpret_cast` when the `uint16_t` is in an rvalue?

Comment: @nog642 You can initialise a variable with the rvalue.